# I want to add customer custom attribute

Tags: magento2

Why nothing is visible in the customer page in the admin panel?

what is wrong?

InstallData.php

```
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface 
$context)

    {

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(

            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,

            'suspend_account_customer',

            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Suspend Account Customer',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );

        $suspend_customer = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'suspend_account_customer');

        $suspend_customer->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer']

        );
        $suspend_customer->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your custom module first.

Add below code to setup folder create CustomerSetup.php file at **app/code/VendorName/Modulename/Setup/CustomerSetup.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

    /**
     * EAV configuration
     *
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $eavConfig;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param Context $context
     * @param CacheInterface $cache
     * @param CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory
     * @param Config $eavConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Context $context,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
        ) {
        $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);
    } 

    /**
     * Gets EAV configuration
     *
     * @return Config
     */
    public function getEavConfig() {
        return $this -> eavConfig;
    } 
}
```

Create InstallData.php file at **app/code/VendorName/Modulename/Setup/InstallData.php** add below code to it

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $this->eavConfig->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'suspend_account_customer',
            [
                'label' => 'User Note',
                'system' => 0,
                'position' => 100,
                'sort_order' =>100,
                'visible' =>  true,
                'note' => '',           
                'type' => 'text',
                'input' => 'textarea',          
            ]
            );

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
                                        ->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'suspend_account_customer')
                                        ->addData(
                                            [
                                                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                                                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                                                'used_in_forms'=> ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit']
                                            ]
                                        );
            $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Run below command after adding this code to your custom module.

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Note: If your test module is already exists, please remove entry from `setup_module` table and then run command

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a UI component XML to show the customer custom attribute in backend customer add/edit page.

I assume you are using a custom extension name "Vendor_Module".

**steo 1)** create **customer_form.xml** under ***/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/base/ui_component/***

File : **customer_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="suspend_account_customer" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**steo 2)**  Flush Magento cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope your custom field will be after this updates.

Answer (score 0):

'used_in_forms' must also include `customer_account_edit`

Answer (score 0):

Lots of required dependencies missing in your setup file

Your NameSpace not declared in your InstallData.php

**Missing dependencies**

Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
Magento\Customer\Model\Customer
Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set
Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory

**also make sure to add the customer attribute to the respective form values**

adminhtml_customer - To get the new field in admin customer account edit form
adminhtml_customer_address - To get the new field in admin customer address edit form
customer_address_edit - To get the new field in storefront customer address edit form
customer_register_address - To get the new field in storefront customer address registration form

Please note you also need to change the respective templates to add your customer attribute in the store front.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\YourModule\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'suspend_account_customer', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Suspend Account Customer',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' =>999,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'suspend_account_customer')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],//you can use other forms also ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

For more information, you can [refer this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162089/695) and if it helps upvote that answer not mine.